# Preventing diagonal flow direction in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, flow-accumulation, flow-direction

I would like to prevent diagonal flow direction/accumulation, as it leads to frequent "river shortcuts". As shown on the picture, instead of following the river in blue, because of the coarse raster resolution, a shortcut is created between the two diagonally adjacent cells (indicated by the red arrows). Here, the grey raster is the filled DEM.

Is there any option in either the flow direction or the flow accumulation function that satisfies this constraint?

[image: DEM filled]

Comment: What is grey raster?

Comment: @FelixIP it is the filled DEM

Comment: There might be what you call shortcut or might not. It's a feature of raster, just live with it. What you are asking makes little sense. 4 directions will result in similar situations all the time

Comment: @FelixIP From an external point of view, I totaly agree that my request makes no sense. But it's in a very specific context, where I'm trying to force the flow obtained from the DEM to follow the polyline in blue. The DEM has been burned in with the polyline, therefore, the only way for the river to escape its channel is through the corners, as displayed on the picture.

Comment: It's not going to happen  when lines are 1 cell size apart.